# i18n - Gettext working locally, but not on server

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I work on a website, written in PHP, and I included translations via PoEdit/Gettext. On my local MAMP Server on my Mac everything is working fine. When I upload it to the Linux server of my Webhoster it is not working. Safe Mode is off and Gettext is enabled - I already checked that.

I do the following:

```
        if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
            $language = $_GET['lang'];
        } else {
            $language = "en_EN";
        }
    putenv("LANG=" . $language);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);   

    // Set the text domain as "s5m"
    $domain = "s5m";
    bindtextdomain($domain, "languages"); 
    bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');  
    textdomain($domain);
```

.mo / .po file is stored at and are named s5m.po / s5m.mo

```
/languages/en_EN/LC_MESSAGES/
```

Does anybody know why it is working on my local, but not on my poster's web server? My internal links after the language has been switched are file.php?lang=en_EN

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: not working **HOW**? No such function? bad translation?

Comment: Hey Marc, no translation at all ...

Comment: Hello, does anybody now if I use something specific which is only workable with PHP > 5.4?

Comment: I have the solutiion. The web server does not support "en_EN" - the server supports "en_US". I had to change this in the coding and in the folder structure. Thats it...

Comment: Maybe you should answer your own question though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solutiion. 
The web server does not support "en_EN" - the server supports "en_US". I had to change this in the coding and in the folder structure. Thats it...